# How to use an Enum in Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I have this (simplified) concern:

```
module Nobi::Personable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :person, :autosave => true    delegate :gender, 
    :gender=, :gender_changed?, :gender_was, :to => :person, :allow_nil => true
    enum gender: { male: "male", female: "female" }
  end
end
```

A Resident has this concern.

Now when I do this:

```
2.6.6> Resident.last.gender
  Resident Load (16.2ms)  SELECT "residents".* FROM "residents" ORDER BY "residents"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Person Load (16.1ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 48], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => "male"
```

However when I ask: **male?** I get:

```
2.6.6> Resident.last.male?
  Resident Load (17.0ms)  SELECT "residents".* FROM "residents" ORDER BY "residents"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => false
```

How is this possible?

If I include the enum on the Person model, it works fine:

```
Person.last.male?
  Person Load (15.9ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" ORDER BY "people"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => true
```

I've created a minimalistic demo app which demonstrates this behavior:
https://github.com/rept/enum_app

```
r = Resident.create(gender: :male, local_gender: :local_male)
r.local_male?
 => true
r.male?
 => false
```

Comment: Does `Resident` define its own `#male?` or `#gender`? You can check with `Resident.new.method(:male?).owner`.

Comment: And is the column an integer or string column?

Comment: Are you sure `Resident.last` is returning the same object?

Comment: Resident.new.method(:male?).owner
 => #<Module:0x00007ffab4dd4c38>
When I remove the enum in the concern and then I get: NoMethodError (undefined method `male?' for #<Resident:0x00007fe331aa37c0>)

Comment: Column is string column and in the DB I can see "male" as well as when I do Resident.last.gender It is indeed the same object that it's returning (testing locally)

Answer (score 1):

> Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the
> database, but can be queried by name.
> -- [ActiveRecord::Enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

You either need to use an integer column with your enum or declare the mapping explicitly. Rails assumes that the values stored in the database are equal to the indices of the array passed to `enum`. Since `"male" != 0` `#male?` will return false.

```
module Nobi::Personable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :person, :autosave => true
    enum gender: {
      male:   "male",
      female: "female"
    }
  end
end
```

While using a string column kind of defeats the point of using an enum in the first place declaring the mapping explicitly is seen as a best practice as it will prevent hard to debug breakages that can be caused by simply reordering the enum values in the array.

And if you need proof:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum gender: [:male, :female] # users.gender is an integer column
end
```

```
irb(main):003:0> User.first
   (0.9ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 9, created_at: "2020-10-29 09:24:12", updated_at: "2020-10-29 09:24:12", gender: "male">
irb(main):004:0> User.first.male?
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> true
```

```
class Resident < ApplicationRecord
  # residents.gender is a string column
  enum gender: {
    male: 'male',
    female: 'female'
  }
end
```

```
irb(main):001:0> Resident.create!(gender: 'male')
   (0.4ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Resident Create (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "residents" ("gender", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["gender", "male"], ["created_at", "2020-10-29 09:56:59.471917"], ["updated_at", "2020-10-29 09:56:59.471917"]]
   (4.7ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Resident id: 1, gender: "male", created_at: "2020-10-29 09:56:59", updated_at: "2020-10-29 09:56:59">
irb(main):002:0> Resident.first.male?
  Resident Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "residents".* FROM "residents" ORDER BY "residents"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> true
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not it.  I've changed it to your version, still get the same result.  You are right about the order, I had it like this before, but been changing it cause of the non-working male? (and female?).  Also documentation https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html does it exactly like I did with :active and active? should work.

Comment: The documentation still assumes that you are using an integer column. I did actually test this and sorry but you're just doing something dumb  and it boils down to bad methodology.

Comment: I added a reproducible example which proves this.

Comment: You are right about the integer (in the Rails example).  However as I said: "I've changed it to your version, still get the same result."  Let me try to make an easy example.

Comment: Yeah bad methodology still as proven above. If you declare the enum in the class body or a concern really doesn't matter at all. You're just using it wrong.

Comment: Added demo app link that demonstrates that it works fine if declared in the class body and not when through concern.

Comment: Yeah, using delegate probably is not going to work at all. ActiveRecord::Enum will query the table of the class where you define the enum and will overwrite your delegated getter. You would really have to declare the enum on the `Person` class and delegate `:male?`, `:female?` to it. This also has nothing to do with the concern.

Comment: it does not use the getter method `#gender` to read the enum value. It actually declares an Enum attribute which is typecast by transforming the enum value into its key. I would encourage you to figure out the basics and read the source before you add levels of complexity. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/404ad9e8acf8ab45ae2314050131a00e57e63b40/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L151

Comment: Sneaking this in after the fact is also an example of the kind of scope creep that makes people really weary when you write "I tried it but it didn't work". If the example provided does not actually reflect it then it doesn't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223820/discussion-between-rept-and-max).